# 2nd Gen iPod (iOS4.x) using iPod keyboard

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, keyboard, bluetooth

Does anyone tried cramming a second gen iPod touch with iOS4 into the iPad keyboard sold by apple?  I've seen [this](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/06/ipad-keyboard-dock-works-with-ios4/) but I'm not sure what the difference in architecture is between the iPhone that the Wired article is talking about and the iPod that I own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original article by Andy Ihnatko can be found here: [The iPad Keyboard Dock works with the iPhone 3GS!](http://ihnatko.com/2010/06/21/the-ipad-keyboard-dock-works-with-the-iphone-3gs/) According to [one of the commenters there](http://ihnatko.com/2010/06/21/the-ipad-keyboard-dock-works-with-the-iphone-3gs/comment-page-1/#comment-84873):

> The iPad keyboard dock also works with my iPod touch 2G (8GB) running iOS4. Great!

But personally, I'm not sure how or why this would be a better solution than a Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the reason is because I found on cheap on Craigslist.